# How to make same width of Tablayout indicator and text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout

In my application i'm working tablayout. everything working fine but i want tablayout text and indicator line both should same size.

but indicator width left and right taking extra space. how to remove extra space or make it both equal width.

do needful

thanks

Comment: post what you have `tried` ?

Comment: tab.setcustomview this is working but i'm getting different issue. is there any native tag to reduce space.

Comment: i want to reduce the width of indicator.